# How do I handle this SFINAE correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I'm running into an issue enabling/disabling overloads based on the traits of a parameter pack. This is for another question I am trying to answer. I have a static `go()` function that should be called if all the `Mixins` types have a static `check()` method. Likewise, there should be another static `go()` method that should be called if the `Mixins` packs *doesn't* have a `check()` method. I attempt to create overloads that enable based on this policy, but for some reason when I call it it chooses the **second** overload which attempts to call `handle()`:

```
template<class T, class...>
using first = T;

template<class... Mixins>
struct Checker
{
public:
    template<class =
             first<void,
                   typename std::enable_if<has_check<Mixins>::value>::type...>>
    static void go()
    {
        auto x{ (Mixins::check(), 0)... };
        (void)x;
    }

    static void go()
    {
        auto x{ (Mixins::handle(), 0)... };
        (void)x;
    }
};

struct A { static void check() { std::cout << "check() "; } };
struct B { static void check() { std::cout << "check() "; } };

int main()
{
    Checker<A, B>::go();
}
```

[***Here is a demo.***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/045d9b9217cd8e2c)

I get an error saying `A` has no member named `handle()`. This has been bugging me but I can't find a way around it. How do I fix this behavior? How do I correctly coordinate overload resolution based on a parameter pack?

Comment: Unrelated: Don't know if you care, but you'll get a compiler error on your `auto x { ...}` lines when `Mixins` is empty. `auto x {};` is ill-formed. The usual workaround is to put an extra leading 0 in the initializer: `auto x{ 0, (Mixins::check(), 0)... };`

Comment: @Casey Thanks for pointing that out. Does the following `0` also matter?

Comment: Yes. A braced-initializer-list is a convenient place to expand a parameter pack that guarantees in-order evaluation. This code uses what I call the "initializer list trick" to evaluate an arbitrary pack expansion expression - in this case `Mixins::check()` and/or `Mixins::handle()` - by using it as a side effect in the construction of a braced init list of integers. Each occurrence of `(Mixins::check(), 0)` in the expansion evaluates one `check` function and - using the comma operator - throws away the result and sticks a `0` in the initializer list.

Comment: When it's all done, you've evaluated all the `check`s and you end up with a syntactically valid initializer with a bunch of zeroes. It only has a name so that we can try to tell the compiler not to warn us about it being unused, either with by casting it to `void` `(void)x` or a bit more portably, passing it to a lambda that just ignores it: `[](std::initializer_list<int>){}(x);`

Comment: @Casey [Your example doesn't compile when the clases do not have a `check()` function](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12a431d8388fff9b). I've tried fixing it but no use. Can you see what's wrong? I'll post another question if we can't figure it out. :)

Comment: Fixed the answer, and (gasp) actually verified that it works in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing to distinguish the two flavors of `go`. Overload resolution will prefer the non-template `go` when both are viable. [The `...` vs. `int` technique works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/babce944d96227d5):

```
template<class... Mixins>
struct Checker
{
private:
    template<class =
             first<void,
                   typename std::enable_if<has_check<Mixins>::value>::type...>>
    static void foo(int)
    {
        auto x{ (Mixins::check(), 0)... };
        (void)x;
    }

    static void foo(...)
    {
        auto x{ (Mixins::handle(), 0)... };
        (void)x;
    }

public:
    static void go() {
        foo(0);
    }
};
```

Since both overloads of `foo` are viable for the call `foo(0)`, but `foo(int)` is a better match than `foo(...)` so that overload resolution will prefer it when it is not SFINAEed out.

EDIT: I made a mistake here, I assumed that

```
template<class =
         first<void,
               typename std::enable_if<has_check<Mixins>::value>::type...>>
```

would correctly SFINAE away the overload of `foo`. However, the error here isn't a substitution failure, since the default for the unnamed function template parameter doesn't depend on parameters of the function template. Typically, when you have a class parameterized on a type `T` and you want to constrain member function `f` based on some property of `T`, you force that dependency with an alias for `T`:

```
template <class T>
struct foo {
  template <class U=T,
            class=typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type>
  void f();
};
```

The same trick won't work in the OP's case, however, since the OP's class is parameterized on a pack and there is no way to provide a default for a parameter pack. We have to be trickier:

```
template<class T = void,
         class = first<T, typename std::enable_if<has_check<Mixins>::value, T>::type...>>
static void foo(int)
{
    auto x{ (Mixins::check(), 0)... };
    (void)x;
}
```

forcing both `first<...>` and the `enable_if<...>` expansion to be valid for SFINAE. [See it at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf5ce4a34062fb36)

Comment: I attempted to use something like this but I guess I made some mistakes while implementing. In any case, I thank you for your help. I shall be using this. :)

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for all your help! :)